# Loading/Adding values into a Datamember of type list<string>(DataContract)?

Tags: list, c#-4.0, datacontract

I have a DC `LoadResult`with  DataMemebers of type `List<string>`

```
public partial class LoadResult : ServiceResult
  {
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Country { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> AuditStatus { get; set; }
  }
```

trying to fill in these values in my DO by doing the following steps.

```
 LoadResult LResult = new LoadResult ();
//Code to connect to database , retrive appropriate values
string x = "some string value retrieved from database";
LResult.Country.Add(x);
```

the last line of code throws me an object reference not set to an instance error, this might be some fundamental thing that i have missed here, but since i have initialized the DC class with the new keyword, i am clueless as to what the error is, Can you help me out here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do

```
LResult.Country = new List<string>();
```

before you add values

Comment: oops, Knew it was such basics, Thanks a lot